# How to stream a Map<Path, List<Path>> to a List<String> containing the absolute path as String?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

My current project is in need of a method that converts a `Map<Path, List<Path>>` to a `List<String>` containing the absolute paths. The `Map` contains `Path`s of files grouped by the directory which contains them.
However, I have to write all the absolute paths of the files found into a dump file, that's why I need `String`s instead of `Path`s.
At the moment, I do it with the following method that uses nested `forEach` calls on the `Map` and its values:

```
public List<String> getAllAbsolutePaths(Map<Path, List<Path>> filesInPath) {
    List<String> absolutePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    filesInPath.forEach((directory, files) -> {
        files.forEach(file -> absolutePaths.add(file.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
    });

    return absolutePaths;
}
```

This is working, but I just want to know a(n even more) modern way to do it by streaming the `keySet` or the `values` of the `Map`.
The problem I have is that I just don't know how to apply the `file.toAbsolutePath().toString()` in the stream. I am just able to collect all the `Path`s as a `List<Path>`:

```
List<Path> filePaths = sqlFilesInDirectories.values().stream()
                            .flatMap(List::stream)
                            .map(Path::toAbsolutePath)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I alter this statement (or write a totally different one) which gives me the desired `List<String>` with the result of `Path.toAbsolutePath().toString()`?

Comment: Just add a second map call `.map(Path::toAbsolutePath).map(Object::toString)`

Comment: @Michael Oh, I hadn't thought about using `Object.toString()` for this! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost done, you just need to call `toString` on resulting list of paths:

```
List<String> strings = filePaths.stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or directly in your stream:

```
List<String> filePaths = sqlFilesInDirectories.values().stream()
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .map(Path::toAbsolutePath)
                        .map(Object::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, that second code is exactly what I need. The first one is cool, too, but it would have meant a second statement, which I was trying to avoid.